# JSON data ingest and sort for efficent search

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I am wanting to take something like the following JSON formatted data and take what is in the person's accessories list and be able to search by the accessory type and have it return a list of those who have the accessory. Would I want to somehow use Swift's inbuilt function of *contains* so I don't have to build a for loop to search? Do I have to create new lists that are named for each accessory type and append the users name to them? How would one do this? I am really not sure how to approach this.

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",  
    "Accessories":["watch","necklace"]
  },
  {
    "name": "James",
    "Accessories":["watch","ring"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Decodable` protocol in Swift 4. First you will have to create a class that defines your `JSON` objects

```
class MyNewClass: Decodable {
    //Make sure your variable names match the keys in your JSON response
    var name: String!
    var Accessories: [String]!
}
```

When you get your JSON response, use the following lines to decode JSON data into class object array and filter that array based on the search criteria

```
do {
    let objects = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyNewClass].self, from: data)
    let people = obj.filter({ $0.Accessories.contains("WHATEVER") }).map{ $0.name }
    //Here you should have an array of people's name that have that accessory
} catch {error
    print(error)
}
```